# Prestashop - Upload image web service in c#

Tags: c#, image, post, prestashop

I'm developing an app for a company. So, for the app they want to upload images to prestashop. The problem basically is that I can't manage to do it through web service. I always get an error 66:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<errors>
<error>
<code>
<![CDATA[66]]>
</code>
<message>
<![CDATA[Unable to save this image]]>
</message>
</error>
</errors>
</prestashop>
```

I've tried everything (postman, httpclient, webclient). And the only thing that worked was the library of Prestasharp. HOWEVER, my boss doesn't want to rely on external libraries for the app. (yeah, I don't get it either). Hence, I was wondering if someone could tell me how to upload the image without the library.
For example, the following code does not work, but I think it's right.

```
string file = @"C:\Users\MyPC\Pictures\Example\50.jpg";
string webAddress = @"http://mywebsite.com/api/images/products/1?ws_key=NUZSHHQ1X456IJQDPXY3GUXG2C6AMAV3";

var client = new HttpClient();

var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("image", file)
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

MessageBox.Show( client.PostAsync(webAddress, content).Result.ReasonPhrase );
```

I've seen people who complain about the same thing, but no one has ever solved this.

I hope you guys can make it,

Kindest regards

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've finally solved this with RestSharp.

```
public string uploadImage(string path, string id_product)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://mywebsite.com/api");
    byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    var request = new RestRequest("images/products/" + id_product + "?ws_key=" + API_KEY, Method.POST);
    request.AddFileBytes("image", file, Path.GetFileName(path));

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    string content = response.Content;

    return content;
}
```

The part where I was getting stuck was the `AddFileBytes` method.

Hope it helps somebody!